# Separate a string within an array & assign it to 2 variables

Tags: php, arrays, string

Ok, so i'm messing around with email lists and i got into a state of a mental deadlock. Here is what i have:

- mailing_list.php // Contains all the details in the form of "Name:Email"
- functions.php // Contains function get_registered_list, which should display the list on a page.

  ```
  function get_registered_list($path = 'mailing.php') {
  $content = file($path); // creates an array of strings of the format "Name:Email"
  // enter code here
  }
  ```

How would you accomplish this:

- Run through the array $content and separate each string as name and email.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the contents with [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) like this:

```
$handle = fopen($path, "r")
$content = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ':');
fclose($handle);
```

Or simply:

```
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$array = str_getcsv($content, ':');
```

You can also parse the array in a `foreach` loop, but this is not recommended, as you have to take care of any special characters within your input file:

```
foreach ( $content as $item ) {
    list($name, $email) = explode(':', $item);
    echo "{$name} ({$email})" . PHP_EOL;
}
```